# Regexp_extract using Google re2

Tags: looker-studio, re2

I need to extract the following text string using google/re2:
Audiences Â» Affinity Categories Â» Food & Dining Â» **Fast Food Cravers**

In sum, any string after no.3 Â»

Would appreciate any help/ guidance, million thanks!

best,
yg

Comment: Is the third `»` always the last, or can there be more? It looks like you've got a character encoding problem somewhere too: `Â` is usually a symptom of double-UTF-8-encoding a character in ISO 8859.

Comment: HI Rup 10, thanks for responding! The third » is not always the last. an example as follow:                                                            
Audiences Â» Affinity Categories Â» Food & Dining Â» Foodies
Audiences Â» Affinity Categories Â» Home & Garden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Regular Expression extracts the 3rd string:

```
(?:[^»]+?Â»){3}\s*(.+?)\s*[\nÂ]
```

You can test it interactively [here](https://regex101.com/r/dQaJeH/1).

[image]

I haven't actually used `re2` before so keep in mind possible syntax differences.